# Speed of programming with Postgres SQL using PHP

Tags: php, python, postgresql

I am writing some database operations for a very large Postgres SQL database table (6 million records). I thought of using a PHP based app for the operations, backed by a database framework like Medoo (http://medoo.in/). I have found the speed slow but am unsure whether this would be the case whatever method I choose, how does the speed of using PHP compare with for example using Python? or more succinctly what's the fastest way to work with a large Postgres SQL database?

The main operations will be calculations based on values in the table generating new virtual or actual rows in the table. The app does not need to be part of a website, however as that's most of my experience its where I started from.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

The query I have tried is:

```
$data = $database->select("large_table", "*");

for ($x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++) 
{
    if ($x<12)//my attempt to only return a few results
    {
        print $data[$x]["id_field"];
        print "<br>";
    }
}
```

This query seems to time out whilst a shorter query of

```
$data = $database->get("large_table", "*");

print $data["id_field"];
```

works

Comment: "I have found the speed slow" - did you pin point the bottleneck? Is it the operations that _have to_ take place in the script? Is it the performance of the queries? Or ...? Or ...?

Comment: Well I ran a basic medoo query to get me a list of the table ids I will add it in

Comment: You mean you issued a query that results in a full table scan and transfered six millions records back to the client? Maybe _that_ is the problem.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that I need to perform some operations on this large dataset, is there a better alternative way of dealing with such large datasets?

Comment: The fastest option is almost always *not* to use an ORM or query generator. You lose a lot of convenience, but can gain a *lot* of speed by writing your own queries directly. The fastest options will be, by far, using direct `libpq` or using PgJDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Medoo like any other database frameworks that use abstraction layer (hence PDO) are forced to fetch all the rows from a result set into memory.

Imagine you return 6M rows, PHP has to allocate and fill this memory with data. This is a real performance bottleneck.

Using a framework based on the native PHP’s native Postgresql libary like [Pomm](http://www.pomm-project.org) would return a lazy, scrollable iterator on results. Unless you explicitly store all the results on the client, it would consume no more memory than needed to store the biggest returned row.

Now, you probably do not want to fetch 6M records back from the database do you ?

You do. Then it is important to understand that buffering the output will also consume the maximum memory needed to fit all the results. You have to ensure the data are streamed to the final client. In this case, network certainly does become the new bottleneck.

Link to the guilty line in Medoo: https://github.com/catfan/Medoo/blob/master/medoo.php#L666

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, unfortunately I do want to return all the records at times (though I suppose I could process in chunks?) One thing I am hoping to be able to do is generate either in a virtual row or a real one in the table extra data based on the values in my table (i.e. interpolated values as well as other operations like summing all the records and such)

Comment: Thanks, might I just ask would this be a problem with whatever programming language/method I use i.e. running a python script on my machine instead? I want to ensure that I am not using an unnecessarily slow way of programming with the database